# List the items in listview according to groups, the data is taken from observable collection

Tags: wpf, binding

i hav one class which stores file information with namelist as itz observableCollection

Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class NameList
    Inherits ObservableCollection(Of FileInfo)

```
' Methods
Public Sub New()
    MyBase.Add(New FileInfo("Willa", "Cather", "warning", "err 1"))
    MyBase.Add(New FileInfo("Isak", "Dinesen", "warning", "err 1"))
    MyBase.Add(New FileInfo("Victor", "Hugo", "warning", "err 1"))
    MyBase.Add(New FileInfo("Jules", "Verne", "warning", "err 3"))
    MyBase.Add(New FileInfo("Victor", "Hugo", "warning", "err 1"))
    MyBase.Add(New FileInfo("Jules", "Verne", "warning", "err 3"))
End Sub
```

End Class

Public Class FileInfo

```
Public _name As String
Public _path As String
Public _image As String
Public _errorGrp As String

Public Property ImageIcon() As String
    Get
        Return _image
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _image = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property PathFile() As String
    Get
        Return _path
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _path = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return _name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _name = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ErrorGroup As String
    Get
        Return _errorGrp
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _errorGrp = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal filePath As String, ByVal image As String, ByVal errorGrp As String)
    Name = fileName
    PathFile = filePath
    ImageIcon = image
    ErrorGroup = errorGrp
End Sub
```

End Class

i need to bind this to the xaml listview item which will be grouped according to errorGroup
i code which i have tried is

```
<Window.Resources >
    <mydata:NameList x:Key="NameListData"/>

  <!--  <DataTemplate x:Key="IconListViewItem" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
             <Image Source="/listViewGroupin;component/Images/ViewType.jpg" Height="19" Width="25" ></Image>
            <TextBlock Foreground="DarkBlue" Text="{Binding ImageIcon}"/>
            <TextBlock Foreground="DarkBlue" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>-->

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key='src' 
                      Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource NameListData}}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
           <!-- <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="ErrorGroup" />-->
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="ErrorGroup"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource src}}"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
        <ListView.GroupStyle >
            <GroupStyle >
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">

                                    <GroupBox BorderBrush="Transparent"  >
                                        <GroupBox.Header >
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >

                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" 
                               Margin="5,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
                                                <Border Height=".2" Width="300" Background="Blue"  ></Border>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </GroupBox.Header>
                                    </GroupBox>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10.4"  />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.View  >
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn Width=" 250" Header="File" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name }">
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Path" Width="350" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PathFile}">
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Error" Width="350"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ErrorGroup}">
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

it is giving me only group names and groups but not the item
please help me

Comment: please someone ans me...plzzzzzzzzzz :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your ListView.GroupStyle as a GroupBox.
GroupBox is a HeaderedContentControl.
You have defined the Group Header, but you also need to define a placeholder for the items -

```
<GroupBox.Content>
   <ItemsPresenter />
</GroupBox.Content>
```